# Is it possible to remote participant track.stop()

Tags: vue.js, twilio, twilio-video

I tried by following codes

```
  // remove particaipant tracks
  vm.tc.currentVideoRoom.participants.forEach((remoteParticipant) => {
      remoteParticipant.tracks.forEach((track) => {
        console.log(track); //here i found the remote participant video and audio track. 

        track.stop() // but here i found "track.stop() is not a function" error
       
      })
  });
```

I check twilio video documentation. but don't found any solution in here.

and i also check GitHub issue [here the link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1067#issuecomment-648330457). the guy mention remote participants tracks stop is not possible.

then how can i stop remote participant tracks using Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a remote track like that. The remote track object is a representation of the track as a stream from the remote participant as a stream. A local track is a representation of a track as a stream from the device's camera or microphone, so when you call `stop`, it stops interacting with the hardware.

So you cannot call `stop` on a remote track, because that would imply you're trying to stop the track coming from the remote participant's camera or microphone.

If you want to stop seeing or hearing a remote track, you can [`detach`](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.21.0/docs/RemoteAudioTrack.html#detach__anchor) the track from the page. If you want to unsubscribe from the track so that you stop receiving the stream of it, you can use the [track subscriptions API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/track-subscriptions). And if you want to actually stop the remote participant's device, you would have to send a message to the remote participant (possibly via the [`DataTrack` API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/datatrack-api)) and have them execute the `track.stop()` locally.